# CSS Two grid DIVs, images and text gives me blackout

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I've been playing with this grid for a while, it's a two grid system in which i'm trying to add two different images. I've added the images with success. However, It's when i try to make two separate containers for the text i would like to place over the images everything goes wrong. Been trying to wrap my head around this for hours without results.

I did succeed to add text over the image with the one column. However, these two columns just won't let me.

What is the best way to solve this?

CSS

```
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section-ad {
clear: both;
padding: 0px;
margin:0;
}

/*  COLUMN  */
.col {
display: block;
float:left;
margin: 0% 0% 0% 1%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUP  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  TWO GRID  */
.span_2_of_2 {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
width: 49.5%;
height: auto;
}
.span_2_of_2 img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.span_1_of_2 img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.col { 
margin: 0% 0 0% 0%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="section-ad group">
<div class="col span_1_of_2">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/5107/files/main-sale-large.jpg?11274335160121521292" />
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_2">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/5107/files/main-plain-x450_ab05c8e5-7269-4d98-b510-8ba5127db9c4.jpg?13010707129353802904" />
</div>
</div>
```

Best Regards,
Robin.

Comment: How are you actually trying to add text over the images. It's easy enough to do without a framework, but a framework may introduce restrictions. If it's just simple text, you could just use `before`/`after`.

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks for the fast reply! Well i did this one earlier:
http://royalstripes.com/pages/third - I found it easier with just one column. However, below that one i'm trying with these two columns, that will have same look with button and a text. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place text over image following way.

Add span inside `col` div and add text inside. And give `position:absolute` and parent div to `position:relative;`. Then you can set it's position using left and right value.

```css
.section-ad {
clear: both;
padding: 0px;
margin:0;
}

/*  COLUMN  */
.col {
display: block;
float:left;
margin: 0% 0% 0% 1%;
position: relative;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUP  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  TWO GRID  */
.span_2_of_2 {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
width: 49.5%;
height: auto;
}
.span_2_of_2 img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.span_1_of_2 img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

span {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 25px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.col { 
margin: 0% 0 0% 0%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-ad group">
<div class="col span_1_of_2">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/5107/files/main-sale-large.jpg?11274335160121521292" />
<span>Some text</span>
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_2">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/5107/files/main-plain-x450_ab05c8e5-7269-4d98-b510-8ba5127db9c4.jpg?13010707129353802904" />
<span>Some text</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your replies.

Ketan - Altough your solution worked, it did not fit my needs. 
However, thanks to your reply i managed to surpass my blackout. So i owe it too you anyway. Thanks!

This might now be the best way, 
but this is how i did it.

CSS

```css
CSS

/*  TVÅ KOLUMN ADVERT # 705x450  */

.span_1_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 1.2em;
  font-size: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
}
.span_1_heading {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.span_2_container h2:before {
  content: '';
  border-top: 1px solid #383a4f;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  left: 35%;
  top: 50px;
}

.span_2_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 1.2em;
  font-size: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
}

.span_2_container h2:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #383a4f;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  left: 35%;
  bottom: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-ad group">
  
  
<div class="col span_1_of_2">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/5107/files/main-sale-large.jpg?5000542013708637763" />
  <div class="span_1_container">
<a href="#" class="service_button">SHOP NOW</a></div>
</div>
  
  
  
<div class="col span_1_of_2">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/5107/files/main-plain-x450_ab05c8e5-7269-4d98-b510-8ba5127db9c4.jpg?13010707129353802904" />
  <div class="span_2_container">
    <h2 class="span_2_heading" style="font-weight: normal; color: #383a4f;">Pocketsquares</h2>
    <p style="font-family: 'Lato'; font-size: 14px; color: #383a4f; line-height: 15px; padding-bottom: 20px;">Explore our premium pocketsquares.</p>
<a href="#" class="advert_button">SHOP NOW</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```